# Having trouble getting a controller in a Razor Class Library to work, What am I missing?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, .net-6.0, razor-class-library

I am having a terrible time getting a REST API controller that is located in an external assembly (in other words, a Razor Class Library) to work. Whenever I make a call to the API via JavaScript, I get a 404 error.

In the Razor Class Library (RCL) I put the controller in its own Area in this structure:

[image: RCL project layout]

The LookupController is decorated with Route attributes:

```
namespace Case.Coding.Areas.CaseCoding.Controllers
{
    [Route("CaseCoding/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class LookupsController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("External")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalAsync()
        {
            return Ok("This is a value. Hoo boy.");
        }
    }
}
```

In the calling project I put a button on the Index page like this:

```
<button id="ClickHere" onclick="GetApiResult();">Click Here</button>
<div id="ClickResult"></div>
```

And the GetApiResult function looks like this:

```
function GetApiResult() {
    var container = $('#ClickResult');
    
    $.ajax({
        url: '/CaseCoding/Lookups/External',
        method: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json'
    })
        .done(function (result, statusText, xhr) {
            var isUndefined = typeof result === 'undefined';
    
            if (isUndefined || result.length == 0) {
                container.append('<p class="pat-comment err">Nothing returned.</p>');
            }
            else {
                container.append(result);
            }
        })
        .fail(function (xhr, statusText, err) {
            container.append('<p class="pat-comment err">' + err + '</p>');
        });
    }
```

I thought the URL to the controller might be different and tried several combinations. Nothing worked, so I thought I might explore the routes attached to the calling project to find out, and found some code (courtesy of https://www.meziantou.net/list-all-routes-in-an-asp-net-core-application.htm) that allowed me to explore them:

```
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.MapGet("/debug/routes", (IEnumerable<EndpointDataSource> endpointSources) =>
        string.Join("\n", endpointSources.SelectMany(source => source.Endpoints)));
}
```

Placed right before the app.Run() statement, this code let me see what I want, but the results flummoxed me. I found the controller in the routes, but the EndPoint was no URL. When navigating to /debug/routes I got this list:

```
/Error
/Index
/Index
/Privacy
/Page1
Case.Coding.Areas.CaseCoding.Controllers.LookupsController.ExternalAsync (Case.Coding)
HTTP: GET /debug/routes
```

There the API is listed out (2nd from bottom), but why isn't it a URL? Does anyone have any idea what is happening here, and (more importantly) how to make my controller route be recognized as a URL so I can call it from JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't reproduce your issue, I can only show you how I did in my side.

I created a new .net 6 MVC project, and I created a web API project in the same solution. Then I create the same `Area` and the same folder and the same Controller.

[image]

Then I right click on the MVC project to add reference. Then choose the web api project.

[image]

This will make the MVC project csproj file be modified.

[image]

Since I created the MVC project first, so I don't need to change the startup project, pressing F5 to run the MVC project, then hitting the URL `https://localhost:7089/CaseCoding/Lookups/External`. Here I changed the POST request to GET for easier to test.

[image]

After making sure the URL, then I write an ajax request in the `index.cshtml` in MVC project.

```
<div>
    <button id="btn">send</button>
</div>

@section Scripts{
    <script>
        $("#btn").click(function () {
            alert(1);
            $.ajax({
                url: "https://localhost:7089/CaseCoding/Lookups/External",
                type:"get",
                success:function(data){
                    alert(data);
                }
            })
        })

    </script>
}
```

[image]